# UseSerilog on IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, serilog

I am getting this on running the application

**{"@t":"2023-07-13T06:47:04.5190466Z","@mt":"Host terminated unexpectedly.","@l":"Fatal","@x":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory' while attempting to activate 'VehicleRepairService.Startup'.\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()\r\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()\r\n   at VehicleRepairService.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\SoleraNA\\Backend\\Inspection\\vehiclerepairservice\\src\\vehiclerepairservice\\Program.cs:line 37"}**

Here is my Program cs file

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .UseKestrel(k => k.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
                .UseCloudFoundryHosting()
                // Add VCAP_* configuration data
                .AddCloudFoundry()
                .ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();  // avoid duplicated log entries
                    loggingBuilder.AddSerilogDynamicConsole();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I am having this warning:

**SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseSerilog(IWebHostBuilder, ILogger, bool, LoggerProviderCollection)' is obsolete: 'Prefer UseSerilog() on IHostBuilder'**

I tried to resolve this with the suggestions I got from stackoverflow and made the following changes:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(k => k.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseCloudFoundryHosting()
                .AddCloudFoundry()
                .ConfigureLogging((builderContext, loggingBuilder) =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                    loggingBuilder.AddSerilogDynamicConsole();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code. Your `CreateHostBuilder` method looks ok. However I think your `Main` method is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This is the important code
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```

With the important part being setting this static property `Log.Logger`.
You can refer to the documentation of the `Serilog.AspNetCore` package [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)
.

Also your initial error might come from incorrect installation of the `Serilog.AspNetCore` package (because it has some dependencies, see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore#dependencies-body-tab)).
Install it again with `dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore` or via the nuget package manager.

I tested on .NET 6.0 with Serilog.AspNetCore 7.0.0 with simple `Startup.cs` file.

Comment: I had the same Main method. But still facing the same error.